# How to integrate the language switcher in HTML + PHP

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4

I'm programming a ecommerce store with php7 and bootstrap. My problem is I select one language dosen't reload the page with language. I probed to introduced into the form and button submit, but i dont' want the button submit but if I want the action.

My code is:

```html
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 idioma">
                            
                                <select name="idioma" id="idioma">

                                    <option value ="es" data-input="es" >Español</option>
                                    <option value ="cat" data-input="cat">Catalan</option>
                                </select>
                        
   </div>
```

Comment: You're not making any sense

Comment: Is your problem redirection? E.g. you want instant redirection when user selects one option? If so, it could be solved by javascript: put this inside select tag: onchange="redirect(this.value)", and add one function in javascript: function redirect(val) {
location.href='http://www.yoursite.com?lang='+val;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are trying to make a website where you can switch between the language displayed on the page, this explains it pretty good : https://www.nomensa.com/blog/2010/7-tips-for-multi-lingual-website-accessibility

Comment: In my web site url i don't pass the parameter lang i don't prefer